# Google Wallet API miss in google-play-services

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-pay

I try use Google Wallet API in my own app. I update my Eclipse and SDK to latest version. I try start example from google `https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/android/resources/instant-buy-android-sample.zip` with last `google-play-services.jar` (file size 632030).

But I get error:

> The import com.google.android.gms.wallet cannot be resolved

because in jar-file miss `wallet` folder.

Where I can get last `google-play-services.jar` with wallet?

Comment: Can you please fill in the interest form at https://getinstantbuy.withgoogle.com/

Answer (score 6):

The library is not the one which can be downloaded from android sdk

you have to submit request by filling a form for now.
In wallet tutorial they have mentioned it

> Important: To run Instant Buy for Android API samples, you'll need to
>   download Google Play Services second-party libraries and include them
>   in your development project. If you don't already have a Google
>   contact to provide access for you, submit the Instant buy interest
>   form. Google will respond to qualified merchants with instructions on
>   how to get the required libraries and credentials.

link is [here](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial)